# Extract substring by repeated StringPattern

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

This code failed, but may exemplify my intention.

```
StringCases["aA1bbbbbbbbbbaA2baA3b...aA4b",Repeated[Shortest["a"~~xx__~~"b"],{2,100}]]
```

I want to get the substring `"aA2baA3b"`. They (`a~~__~~b` is one string pattern) are in succession.

single `"aA3b"` is not expected to get and should be omitted.

```
StringCases["aA1bbbbbbbbbbaA2baA3b...aA4b",Repeated[Shortest["a"~~__~~"b"],{2,100}]]
```

gives

> "aA1bbbbbbbbbbaA2baA3b"

Comment: In my opinion, it is bad behavior to ask one question, get an answer, and then edit the question, obliterating the original, into something quite different. You should preserve the original question in your edits, and add the new one as a clearly marked edit

Comment: I think You should tell us what do You **want to do**. Not what result You want to get, because it can be obtained in many ways. Those solutions will fail in general because they were created to work with special case.

Comment: @m_goldberg Ok, I'll take care of that in the future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I said already in chat, what's breaking your neck here is the naming of the pattern `xx_`. So if you leave that out, everything should work

```
StringCases["aA1baA2baA3b...aA4b", 
 Repeated[Shortest["a" ~~ __ ~~ "b"], {2, 100}]]

(* {"aA1baA2baA3b"} *)
```

Let me elaborate in more detail, why this happens. If you name the pattern, it can no longer stand for everything in each single repetition. It needs to be the same then. For the purpose of demonstration let me simplify your example to

```
StringCases["aA1baA2baA3b...aA4b", 
 Shortest["a" ~~ xx__ ~~ "b"] :> xx]

(* {"A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"} *)
```

As you see, we get a list of results from `StringCases` and in each result the `xx_` stands for something else. Now lets assume we want 2 repetitions of your pattern, but we just write them down, without using `Repeated`

```
StringCases["aA1baA2baA3b...aA4b", 
 PatternSequence[Shortest["a" ~~ xx__ ~~ "b"], Shortest["a" ~~ xx__ ~~ "b"]]]

(* {} *)
```

this brings no result, because you force with the naming of the pattern, that it is the same in both appearances. But for such a thing nothing matches. When you now change `"aA2b"` to `"aA1b"1`, you get a match, because then you have two equal things which can fill `xx__`.

### Update

Regarding your comment

> Hi, I add one case, `StringCases["aA1bbbbbbbbbbaA2baA3b...aA4b",Repeated[Shortest["a"~~__~~"b"],‌​{2,100}]]`, how can I only get `"aA2baA3b"` – HyperGroups 7 hours ago

Mr.Wizards answer is completely sound, but let me give another solution different to him. The question here is, what you are trying to achieve, because if feels like you are throwing example after example only to see how it is done.

Let me first explain what happens in your comments example. The first repetition of `Shortest["a"~~__~~"b"]` is matched as follows

```
"a" ~~ "A1bbbbbbbbb" ~~ "b"
```

which is perfectly fine. What you can do at this point is say *I only want one "b" matched*. Then you could say that the `__` is allowed to match everything `Except` a `"b"`:

```
StringCases["aA1bbbbbbbbbbaA2baA3b...aA4b", 
  Repeated[Shortest["a" ~~ Except["b"] .. ~~ "b"], {2, 100}]]
```

Comment: Hi, I add one  case,`StringCases["aA1bbbbbbbbbbaA2baA3b...aA4b",Repeated[Shortest["a"~~__~~"b"],{2,100}]]`,  how can I only get `aA2baA3b`

Comment: @HyperGroups See my update.

Answer (score 6):

Regarding your revised question you may be seeking something like this:

```
StringCases[
  "aA1bbbbbbbbbbaA2baA3b...aA4b", 
  Repeated[Shortest["a" ~~ __ ~~ "b"], {2, 100}],
  Overlaps -> True
]
```

> ```
> {"aA1bbbbbbbbbbaA2baA3b", "aA2baA3b"}
> ```

You can use `SortBy[%, StringLength] // First` to get the shortest of these results.

Comment: Yes, something like this, If we are doing `StringReplace`, I wonder whether there could be one direct string pattern to search and replace.